# Failure to forward DNS requests with dnsmasq to a jump server

Tags: 16.04, networking, ssh, dns, dnsmasq

My goal is to forward DNS requests for certain work-related hosts to a jump server, which is able to resolve those requests.

I mapped port `53` on the jump server with `5353` locally as following:

```
ssh -L 5353:localhost:53 pritzl@jump
```

In this session, I am able to `nslookup server.work`. Now I want to be able to do the same on my machine at home.

I configured `dnsmasq.conf` in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf` as following:

```
server=/google.com/1.1.1.1
server=/server.work/127.0.0.1#5353
```

Then, I restarted network manager: `service network-manager restart`.

Now, let's test:

- For `google.com`, I get:

```
pritzl@pritzl-vault:~$ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.17.78
```

- For `server.work`, I get:

```
pritzl@pritzl-vault:~$ nslookup server.work
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

- For `server-2.work`, I immediately get:

```
pritzl@pritzl-vault:~$ nslookup server-2.work
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find server-2.work: NXDOMAIN
```

(Regarding the latter, I guess this makes sense, as my ISP's DNS doesn't know `server-2.work`, and can response immediately. I guess I should alter my `dnsmasq.conf` to include everything from `*.work`, but it's a good test here to be restrictive.)

Something is wrong, but I don't know what. How do I continue with this?

**additional information**

I also tried setting `server=/google.com/127.0.0.1#5353` in `dnsmsaq.conf`, and then `nslookup google.com` doesn't work anymore (besides the conclusion that nothing works, just not only work-related hosts). I am not sure what this means *exactly*, but I thought it was an interesting test to add here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man ssh`:

> ```
> -L local_socket:remote_socket
>          Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket
>          on the local (client) host are to be forwarded to the given host
>          and port, or Unix socket, on the remote side.
> ```

DNS commonly uses UDP, not TCP. Whilst TCP can be used, and dnsmasq has limited support for this, it's not given that your remote DNS server supports (or are configured) for this.

Comment: Well...that makes sense, now. Thank you for pointing that out. I should probably open a new question for this, but my question then is how I should approach this instead? As said, I want to forward DNS requests for specific work hosts to the DNS server of a jump server. I actually came from here: https://superuser.com/questions/1456720/forward-dns-request-to-my-works-jump-server (this question was asked by myself as well).

Comment: It depends. One way would be to use a VPN capable of transporting UDP, for instance OpenVPN. As you only transport queries, not the requests for the target services to the jump box, would it be possible to use externally visible DNS? Or use a VPN for everything for remote work?

Comment: I can see your concerns, regarding **just** DNS and the usage of OpenVPN. I'll open a new question with more context. I'm learning step by step, so bear with me.

Comment: I would suggest discussing this with whoever you're performing the work for. They probably have a setup for remote work. If not, thread carefully. For my workplace, using non-standard remote access would be grounds of termination.

Comment: Good idea, I did not realize that. I will contact them. For what it is worth, I got it working. I did not realize DNS goes over UDP, so thank you for explaining that.